# UIButton subclass, set NSLayoutConstraint on titleLabel

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints, subclass

So, I created a `UIButton` subclass and within this subclass, I wanted to set a new autolayout constraint like this:

```
self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.titleLabel, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -2))
```

Apparently, and it makes sense, in the `UIButton` class there's already a constraint that sets the `UIButton`'s `centerY` equal to the `titleLabel`'s `centerY`. As a result, I have conflicting constraints.

Is there a way to invalidate the constraint that is set in the `UIButton` class or modify it ?

Comment: Can you please explain why you are trying this , you have already property  to set title edge insets `setTitleEdgeInsets`

Comment: Actually, i didn't consider it but this function seems to have been created especially for that. Thanks!

Comment: if you must then use `removeConstraint(self.titleLabel)` but a better approach would be `setTitleEdgeInsets`

Comment: `setTitleEdgeInsets` doesn't work when using in `layoutSubviews`